# How to display the error vector on ground control points in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with dimensions of 439 * 419 ( 439*419=183941 cell) that includes height information(this height value contain error). I selected about 80 cell (with a good dispersion in the study area) from this 183941 cells. for this 80 selected cells, I have the correct height value. now I want to show the differences between wrong and correct height value in this 80 selected cells with a vector. I actually want the output like the picture below:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5foz.png)

Is there any command that I can do this in MATLAB software ??
Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Without any additional information or code, the only thing we can say is that you should use the [stem3](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stem3.html) function for creating the plot.

If you want more detail, please edit your question by adding how you choose the points, the code you tried, etc.